# Adding a Banner to my C# App

Tags: c#, winforms, banner-ads

Is it possible to add a dynamic banner field, within a compiled application, that pulls an image and hyperlink from a database on a cloud server somewhere?

I currently have a static banner in my app - using the following code, but I would like to be able to change that at a server somewhere rather than having to create an auto-update for a new sponsor.

```
private void BannerAd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("http://www.DatabaseLinkToSponseredAdvertiserLinkGoesHere");
}
```

Comment: Why not just generate the image on the server side (with ASP.NET or something) and download the image to the c# app?

Comment: I'd say add two fields for URL and content, and a three column table in the database (id[int, identity, pk],url,content). on load, make up a random int and pull the corresponding row. you might want a stored proc telling you how many rows you have (so you can pull a random row with no issues)

Comment: Kor/Alex, do either of you know what Form components I would insert into my app to display the banner?  I am fairly decent with static apps, but this is my first foray into remote assets.

Comment: Of course but, what have you tried? How do you connect to your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but what are you using for a DBMS?

For example, at my workplace we are using SQL Server w/T-SQL on my current project, and we use the Image Data Type to help achieve what you are looking for ([MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx))

Doing the above can be costly, especially if you have a lot of high-res images. So with that in mind, you could alternatively have a table with a key field and value field that points to the image path on your application server.

e.g.

```
KEY      |    VALUE
BannerX  |    ~/Images/Sponsored/BannerX.png
BannerY  |    ~/Images/Sponsored/BannerY.png
BannerZ  |    ~/Images/Sponsored/BannerY.png
```

If you make the Key field the primary key, then you will only need to add future C# code if you add new keys to the Database.

Comment: So, use a dictionary list?  And point to the image?  What about a the corresponding hyperlink?

Comment: Perhaps I should have made it more clear, but this would be a database table such as dbo.sponsored_images. You then have the power either to retrieve them in the C# code by Key, or to get all in a List, and rotate the images at random.